# SSIS source connection via Azure Integration runtimes

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

[image: Integration runtime service]

As per upper image client hosted the integration runtime service in azure and there's SQL secure connection of client's on premise SQL database. So I want to use that connection in SSIS package as a source. Directly I can't use that SQL server name and password because it's encrypted via azure.So Is there any way to use that connection in SSIS?

Comment: if you're running the package is being run on the SQL Server on premises instance (I assume in SSISDB), wouldn't it make use of the existing "secure" connection?

Comment: Package will be host in azure SSIDB. Also client will not provide the on premise credential directly. It will be provided via as per upper image of azure integration run-time.

Comment: So what does the On-premises host have to do with any of this?

Comment: I want to fetch data from on premise server to Azure data ware house via ssis.

Comment: If this is a new piece of work, there is no reason to use SSIS and I would discourage it.

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-proxy-ssis#configure-an-azure-ssis-ir-with-your-self-hosted-ir-as-a-proxy says you can use self hosted runtime as a "proxy" (I think it means network connectivity only) but it is _very_ complicated. It certainly doesn't say you can reuse credentials. Though it's hard to work out

Comment: Thanks Nick, Yes it's new piece of work. Without SSIS it's nearly impossible incremental load of data via azure data factory from on premise database to azure database.Yeah there's only facility of sql query and that's not only enough for the case of incremental load.

Comment: No it's actually easier in data factory because you don't have to build a package for every single table. You just need to install a self hosted runtime on-premises and link it to your data factory. It's far less complicted than trying to use SSIS. My advice: definitely investigate a self hosted runtime and avoid SSIS.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I will let you know if i get any work around for incremented load of data from on premise to azure data warehouse via data factory.

Answer (score 0):

From the documents, we can get that the Data factory only can run the SSIS package on [Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime (IR)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#azure-integration-runtime), we can not using [Self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#self-hosted-integration-runtime) for SSIS.

Such as: [Run an SSIS package with the Execute SSIS Package activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-invoke-ssis-package-ssis-activity), all the documents never mentioned Self-hosted integration runtime.

Since the self-host integration runtime is exist, you can using the it to fetch data from on premise server to Azure data ware house with the Data Factory copy activities.

You could reference bellow tutorials:

1. [Copy data to and from SQL Server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server)
2. [Copy and transform data in Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly Azure
   SQL Data Warehouse) by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse)

Hope this helps.